Probability that a brownian motion with drift hits a barrier before a time barrier.
Consider a brownian motion with drift and diffusion, $B_t$ defined as:
$$
B_t = \mu t + \sigma W_t,
$$
where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, $\sigma > 0$, and $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.
We define two absorbing barriers:

Lower barrier: $-a < 0$
Upper barrier: $b > 0$

And the related stopping times:
$$
\tau_{-a} = \inf \{ s \geq 0 : B_s \leq -a \},
$$
$$
\tau_b = \inf \{ s \geq 0 : B_s \geq b \},
$$
The goal is to find the probability that the process hits the upper barrier $b$ before the lower barrier $-a$ and does so before a fixed time horizon $T > 0$. Mathematically, this is:
$$
P(\tau_b < \tau_{-a}, \tau_b \leq T).
$$
To approach this problem I have attempted to use backwards time Kolmogorov equations and try to solve the given PDE.
Define $u(x, t)$ as the probability that, starting from position $x$ at time $t$, the process $B_t$ hits the upper barrier $b$ before the lower barrier $-a$, and within the remaining time $T - t$. Thus:
$$
 u(x, t) = P_x(\tau_b < \tau_{-a}, \tau_b \leq T - t).
$$
Using the backward Kolmogorov equation, $u(x, t)$ satisfies:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \mu \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 0,
$$
with the following conditions:

Spatial Domain:$-a < x < b$
Boundary Conditions:

At $x = -a$, $u(-a, t) = 0$ for all $0 \leq t \leq T$
At $x = b$, $u(b, t) = 1$ for all $0 \leq t \leq T$


Terminal Condition: At $t = T$, $u(x, T) = 0$ for all $-a < x < b$

I have managed to solve the problem on the no-drift scenario with diffusion (so, same problem as before, just setting $\mu=0$ in the previous PDE):
$$
P = u(0, 0) = \frac{a}{a+b} + \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{2(-1)^m}{m\pi} \sin\left(\frac{m\pi a}{a+b}\right) \exp\left(-\frac{\sigma^2 m^2 \pi^2 T}{2(a+b)^2}\right).
$$
however I struggle to approach the drift case, does anyone see any way to approach the PDE solution?
